# How to sort products in category by price but only on stock in OpenCart?

Tags: php, sorting, opencart

How to sort products in category by price but out of stock be on the end on category? 
I want to show first stock items sorted by price.

I edit `catalog/controller/product/category.php` but I can't make quantity argument.

```
  if (isset($this->request->get['sort'])) {
     $sort = $this->request->get['sort'];
  } else {
     //$sort = 'p.date_added';
     $sort = 'p.price';
  }

  if (isset($this->request->get['order'])) {
     $order = $this->request->get['order'];
  } else {
     //$order = 'DESC';
     $order = 'ASC';
  }
```

**Opencart 1.5.4**

Comment: you want to sort products by price on category page ?

Comment: Yes, I want. And know how. But I want to hide "out of stock" items. Not exacly hide I want they at end of category. 

Something like soft price&&stock.